# Getting HBITMAP from image path of any image in C

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap

I am currently working with images in C & WinAPI, and I want to generate an HBITMAP from a given image path (of a `.png` picture, for example).

I have managed to write the function solution using GDI+:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")

HBITMAP generateBitmap(const char* filePath)
{
    HBITMAP res = NULL;
    std::string fileNameStr = filePath; //convert from char* to std::string
    std::wstring unicodeFileName(fileNameStr.begin(), fileNameStr.end()); //convert from string to wstring
    GdiPlus::Bitmap bitmap(unicodeFileName.c_str(), false); //gets bitmap from path
    bitmap.GetHBITMAP(0, &res);
    return res;
}
```

The problem with this solution, however, is that it requires the GDI+ library, which does not have (as far as I know) a C-compatible version (as it uses features such as classes and templates, it is for C++ only).

Is there any way to implement the function `generateBitmap` in C, without using C++?

Comment: [`CreateBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createbitmap)

Comment: This allows me to create an HBITMAP, not load it from an image file... Or am I missing something there?

Comment: open file by self, map it to memory or read. and then use this api

Comment: Do I just read the entire file to an array of bytes?

Comment: also exist `LoadImage`

Comment: Last time I checked LoadImage only works for icons and bitmaps, not for PNG and JPG

Comment: in this case use WIC interfaces.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-bitmap-flat

Comment: "*it requires the GDI+ library, which does not have (as far as I know) a C-compatible version*" - GDI+ has a [Flat API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-graphics-flat) available for C.

Comment: GDI+ uses the [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-lh) internally. You can use the WIC directly, if you want to, or use GDI+' Flat API. Neither one is exceptionally convenient to use. What's the reason that you must use C (rather than C++)?

Comment: Also, `//convert from string to wstring` is a lie. There is no conversion going on. It's just widening code units from 8 bits to 16 bits. That widening results in bogus encodings for 1 out of every 2 possible values a `char` can represent. See [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/).

Comment: @IInspectable I know that. Believe me, I have done my research on UNICODE. I understand that this isn't really a convertion, but I wrote that comment for simplicity. "Create a new wstring that is based on the given string we got" is just too long for a comment

Comment: That's too long, and wrong as well. The short, concise, and true comment would have been: `// create garbage of correct type`. Still, that doesn't answer the important question: Why do you have to use C in your implementation, and cannot use C++?

Comment: My entire program is written in C, and I don't want to switch to C++ just for that purpose.

Comment: I do realise that in C I would need to iterate through the path to convert it to unicode (or use swprintf). I'm fine with that.

Comment: Write a static library in C++, `extern "C"` your API, make sure to not leak any C++ into the unsuspecting C code (like exceptions), and link it into your C program.

Comment: The thing is, this code is already a part of a library which I am writing and I want to be written in C. I prefer not to use C++ at all if possible.

Comment: If C is it, you can use either GDI+' Flat API (more convenient, with more esoteric types at the API boundary) or the WIC (more flexible, more standard COM types, more standard error reporting through `HRESULT`s, more tedious/laborious).